# Using System.Dynamic to introspect COM objects

Tags: c#, dynamic, com-interop

How can I use IDynamicMetaObjectProvider to introspect COM objects? Specifically, given an arbitrary COM object, I want to return a Dictionary where the Key is the Property name, and the Value is the string value of the property in the COM object (if the property value isn't a string, skip it).

How can I get the property names and their values at runtime like this?

Comment: Just use Reflection like you normally do, dyn.GetType().GetProperties() etc.

Comment: @Hans That doesn't seem to work, it just returns the ComObject static properties

Comment: Worked fine on my machine.  Make sure the reference is of type dynamic, not object.  And that the COM server implements IDispatch.

Comment: @Hans That might be my problem, it *was* dynamic but I was casting it to object. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can't really; objects are not required to implement IDynamicMetaObjectProvider in order to provide dynamic functionality, it's a hook that allows them to contribute in the binding process.

For this kind of operation, you would still have to drop down to using Reflection to get the members and the values.

Comment: System.__ComObject seems to do so, since the VS debugger view is able to evaluate it as a Dynamic object

Comment: Maybe this adds some additional help: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30919888/introspecting-com-object-in-c.aspx

Comment: @Paul Betts: Are you saying you can cast `System.__ComObject` to `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`?  If so, then why not just perform a direct cast in code?  It seems that it would have been pretty simple to do?

Comment: I think so, but what I'm asking is, how can I use IDynamicMetaObjectProvider to walk the property list?